# TCPDF alignment issue with <b> tag

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

We are facing a strange issue where TCPDF is not printing content inside the `<b>` tag properly. It is getting misaligned.

Following is the code:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->AddPage();

$html = <<<EOF
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-gb">
    <head>
        <title data-cke-title="Rich Text Editor, idServiceTemplate">Rich Text Editor, idServiceTemplate</title>
    </head>
    <body contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr cke_show_borders" spellcheck="true">
        <p align="left" style="text-align: left;">
            <span style="font-size: 10.5pt;">
                <span style="background: #ffffff;">
                    <span>
                        <b><span style="font-size: 9pt;"><span><span style="color: #000000;">GALL</span></span></span></b>
                        &nbsp;
                        <b>
                            <span style="font-size: 9pt;">
                                <span><span style="color: #000000;">BLADDER</span></span>
                            </span>
                        </b>
                        <span style="font-size: 9pt;">
                            <span><span style="color: #000000;">: The gall bladder is distended and appears extra hepatic in location. No calculus is seen within it.&nbsp;</span></span>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>

EOF;

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_006.pdf', 'I');
```

Suppose if I add a space before  then it is getting printed correctly.For example:

Issue with: `<b><span style="font-size: 9pt;"><span><span style="color: #000000;">GALL</span></span></span></b>`. [Check print here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OwhOC9lz2i2X-RfxDQgNOI48GXk9Nb8t/view?usp=sharing).

but following is working fine

`<b><span style="font-size: 9pt;"><span><span style="color: #000000;">GALL</span></span></span> </b>` [Check print here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p17xwK3m-SSZVMBCGd09B7_bm24k_t_7/view?usp=sharing)

Does anyone know what is the issue here?

Comment: From an HTML point of view this might be a TCPDF bug [assuming their restricted dialect does not have very weird parts], but just for the sake of poking around -- what happens if you play with the `&nbsp;` after the GALL? (The line-breaks in the inline element is pedantically wrong, but at least they correctly cause extra spaces in output.)

Comment: @MingyeWang If I am removing the &nbsp; then issue is not occurring but as it is ckeditor so I don't have control over html

Comment: Hey, have you checked [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/pdfview/issues/77284) out? It seems like a bug from the package.